# Searching for specific groups using permutation without repetition and greedy aproach (homework)

Tags: combinations, permutation, greedy

I'm student of second year on CS. On my algorithms and data structures course I've been tasked with following problem:

```
Input:
2<=r<=20
2<=o<=10
0<=di<=100

Output:
number of combinations
or "NO" if there are none
```

- r is number of integers
- di are said integers
- o is number of groups

I have to find the number of correct combinations. The correct combination is one where every integer is assigned to some group, none of the groups are empty and the sum of integers in every group is the same:

For an instance:

```
r = 4;
di = {5, 4, 5, 6}
o = 2;
```

So the sum of integers in every group should add up to 10:

```
5 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 20
20 / o = 20 / 2 = 10
```

So we can make following groups:

```
{5, 5}, {4, 6}
{5, 5}, {6, 4}
{5, 5}, {4, 6}
{5, 5}, {6, 5}
```

So as we can see, the every combination is essentialy same as first one.( The order of elements in group doesnt matter.)

So actually we have just one correct combination: {5, 5}, {4, 6}. Which means output is equal to one.

Other examples:

```
r = 4;
di = {10, 2, 8, 6}
o = 2;

10 + 2 + 8 + 6 = 26;
26 / o = 26 / 2 = 13
```

There is no way to make such a sum of these integers, so the output is "NO".

I had a following idea of getting this thing done:

```
struct Input { // holds data
    int num; // number of integers
    int groups; // number of groups
    int sumPerGroup; // sum of integers per group
    int *integers; // said integers
};

bool f(bool *t, int s) { // generates binary numbers (right to left"
    int i = 0;
    while (t[i]) i++;
    t[i] = 1;
    if (i >= s) return true;
    if (!t[i + 1])
        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            t[j] = 0;
    return false;
}

void solve(Input *input, int &result) {
    bool bin[input->num];  // holds generated binary numbers
    bool used[input->num]; // integers already used
    for (int i = 0; i < input->num; i++) {
        bin[i] = 0;
        used[i] = 0;
    }

    int solved = 0;
    do {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < input->num; i++) {  // checking if generated combination gets me nice sum
            if (sum > input->sumPerGroup) break;
            if (bin[i] && !used[i]) sum += input->integers[i]; // if generated combination wasnt used before, start adding up
            if (sum == input->sumPerGroup) { // if its add up as it shoul
                for (int j = 0; j < input->num; j++) used[j] = bin[j]; // mark integers as used
                solved ++; // and mark group as solved
                sum = 0;
            }
            if (udane == input->groups) { // if the number of solved groups is equal to number of groups
                result ++; // it means we found another correct combination
                solved = 0;
            }
        }

    } while (!f(bin, input->num)); // as long as I can get more combinations 
}
```

So, the main idea is:
1. I generate combination of some numbers as binary number
2. I check if that combination gets me a nice sum
3. If it does, I mark that up
4. Rinse and repeat.

So for input from first example {5, 4, 5, 6} in 2 groups:

```
5 4 5 6
-------
0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0
  ...
1 0 1 0 -> this one is fine, becouse 5 + 5 = 10; I mark it as used
1 1 1 0
  ...
0 1 0 1 -> another one works (4 + 6 = 10); Marked as used
So far i got myself 2 working groups which is equal to 2 groups - job done, it's a correct combination.
```

The real problem behind my idea is that I have no way of using some integer once I mark it as "used". This way in more complicated examples I would miss quite alot of correct groups. My question is, what is correct approach to this kind of problem? I've tried recursive approach and it didin't work any better (for the same reason)

Another idea I had is to permutate (std:next_permutate(...) for instance) integers from input each time I mark some group as used, but even on paper that looks silly.

I don't ask you to solve that problem for me, but if you could point any flaws in my reasoning that would be terrific.

Also, not a native speaker. So I'd like to apologise in advance if I butchered any sentence (I know i did).

Comment: Shouldn't you use greedy approach somewhere as title says? For instance see [Knapsack problem greedy solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Knapsack_problem#Greedy_approximation_algorithm) to get some ideas.

Comment: It looks promising, thank you. In title I tried to approximate the general idea. I do realise I could got it wrong.